# valgrind on the ARM9?

Tags: arm, valgrind, embedded-linux, arm9

I see that valgrind has an ARM7 target, but I find conflicting information on whether valgrind has support for the ARM9. The ARM9 target I am working with is running linux.

Has anyone specifically succeeded in using valgrind on an ARM9 target?  If so, any pointers you can offer would be helpful, including "how did you build it?".

Thanks

-z

Answer (score 7):

Valgrind runs on ARM-v7 (architecture name), not ARM7 (chip family name).  ARM7 is a name of a fairly old chip family (which uses architecture ARM-v4), as is ARM9 (ARM-v5).  Are you sure that your chip is an ARM9 and not a Cortex-A9 (which uses the ARM-v7 architecture)?  If it's really an ARM9, you are out of luck.  If it's a Cortex, it should work.

Comment: Checking /proc/cpinfo I see that Processor has the following string: ARM926EJ-S rev 0 (v5l)...  Not sure which generation that puts this particular ARM into.

Comment: ARM926EJ-S is ARMv5, which is in fact indicated in very abbreviated form by the output you attach; (v5l) - ARMv5, little-endian.