# Valgrind in ARM Cortex-A8 Issue "configure: error: Unsupported host architecture"

Tags: arm, valgrind, embedded-linux, cortex-a8

I have found in my actual program for ARM CortexA8 with linux a following issue:

```
´*** glibc detected *** ./PRUssExternal: double free or corruption (top): 0x00024fe8 ***´
```

I`m searching for that in the web and I found that the most usefull program to manage this is issue is Valgrind.

[How to track down a double free or corruption error in C++ with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902064/how-to-track-down-a-double-free-or-corruption-error-in-c-with-gdb)

Then I try to compile to my system in a cross compilation, with the following options in the configuration. I´m using Valgrind 3.8.1

> @-virtual-machine:~/valgrind-3.8.1$
>   CC=arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-gcc CFLAGS="-pipe -Os -mtune=cortex-a8
>   -march=armv7-a -mabi=aapcs-linux -msoft-float -I/opt/OSELAS.Toolchain-2011.11.3/arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.14.1-binutils-2.21.1a-kernel-2.6.39-sanitez/sysroot-arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/OSELAS.Toolchain-2011.11.3/arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.14.1-binutils-2.21.1a-kernel-2.6.39-sanitez/sysroot-arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib" ./configure -prefix=/opt/valgrid -host=arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi
>   -target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi -build=x86_64-ubuntu-linux

And the output of this configuration is:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-strip... arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-gcc... arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-gcc... gcc3
checking whether arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-gcc -E
checking for arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-g++... arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-g++... gcc3
checking for arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-ranlib... arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for gdb... /usr/bin/gdb
checking dependency style of arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi-gcc... gcc3
checking for diff -u... yes
checking for a supported version of gcc... ok (4.6.2)
checking build system type... x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabi
checking for a supported CPU... no (arm)
configure: error: Unsupported host architecture. Sorry
```

In the last line of this output, My Issue is appeared although I looked for some information and the Cortexa8 it is one of the supported plattaforms.

[valgrind on the ARM9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378152/valgrind-on-the-arm9)

For that reason my question is whether my board is not supported because the libraries that I use are not compatible or it could be other reason. Or in other hand I could compile the valgrind without fear and jump this checking.

Thanks for your time

-Regards

Breci01010...

Comment: According to http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4CD93681.2020608%40yandex.ru&forum_name=valgrind-users , this could be an effect of your unusually explicit toolchain name. So following that, you could try --host=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabi.

Comment: Thanks unixsmurf, I have already tested changing to the new configuration in host and so it works propertly.
Thanks for your time
-Regards

Comment: Hi, I have compiled and installed succesfully the valdgrid in the CortexA8. But the problem that I find now it is because I don´t use the standard C libraies 

[How to compile valgrid](http://blog.galemin.com/2010/10/how-to-build-valgrind-3-6-0-for-beagleboard-xm-on-ubuntu/)

How someone knows other system works more friendly with non-standard libraries that isn´t gdb. 
-Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You should edit configure file. Find a line "armv7*" and change it to "arm*" - this would be enough.

Comment: The configure file is a generated one. So, I first waited for the error. Made the change in the file and then incrementally compiled again. I just wanted to know where is the configure file getting copied from?